# What is the meaning of ♦R?

Tags: bug, chat

I was trying to create a chat room with the name **"Love for developer"** and I got the message

*This room might already exist.*.

[image]

But there I saw this **♦R**. What is the meaning of this? Is this a moderator, the same as **Community♦** or what? That name is nothing like the name I chose, which is confusing me.

---

**Edit:** When I click the `R` link it shows something like below:

[image]

And if I click the `R` tag there, it's going to [R Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). This has got nothing to do with the room I'm trying to create, so this is the reason for my confusion here. :(

Comment: Tooltip of ♦: `Moderators have full access to this room`

Comment: @Pang I know that. But that moderator name is just `R`?

Comment: `R` is name of room, I believe.

Comment: @Pang Nope. I am providing the room name as `Love for developer`

Comment: @Ramesh what exactly is your question here... You seem to be asking what the diamond means there (which you have an answer to) but at the same time you appear to have gotten to asking this question because you're trying to create a new room or possibly confused about how tags work?

Comment: Actually I am confused with, Why **♦R** is showing while creating a chat room? and what is the mean of R? That is my question @JonClements

Comment: It seems clear from the comments that this should have been a *bug report*. Why, if he was creating a room called *Love for developer* would it warn him that it might already exist and show him the *R* chat room? That seems like a bug to me, @JonClements. I've edited in information from the comments, hopefully clarifying the problem.

Comment: @Will: I don't think the asker was ever sure what he was intending to ask anyways.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, he *was* confused...

Comment: @Will I can get it to suggest F# without a single F in the name and change developer to developc and you get C as a room suggestion. Some *interesting* suggestion mechanism going on there...

Comment: Good, then bug.

Comment: @Will appears so... which is odd... the search on SE is normally so accurate, robust and reliable... :p

Answer (score 11):

1. What **♦R** means

   Well, ♦R is a chatroom just like any others. The name of this chatroom is simply "R", and is about the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) programming language like you noticed when you clicked on those links.
2. Why it's suggesting **♦R** when you create your room.

   No clue why it does, but as mentioned by others, it could
   have to do something about your chatroom containing the letter "R",
   since your chatroom name would be "Love fo**r** develope**r**". But considering that your chatroom will be about something completely different, you can ignore this suggestion and check the *"Thanks, but the topic of my to-be-created room is entirely different"*.
3. What the diamond shape (♦) means.

   This symbol means that moderators have full access to the chatroom regardless of any other setting. In this case, it means that moderators have full access to the R chatroom. It's usually displayed in combination with the lock symbol, because in those rooms (Gallery) only approved users can talk. Moderators however, do not have to be approved to be able to talk.
4. If the diamond shape means the same thing as the diamond shape for **Community♦**.

   No, but they're related. As I said before, the diamond shape in this case means that moderators have full access to the chatroom. In the case of Community♦, it means that Community is a moderator. So they both involve moderators, but when it's next to someone's name, it means that they are a moderator, while in the case of ♦R, it means that those moderators have full access to the room.

Comment: I'm curious now as to the historical reasons of displaying the diamond. It does seem a little superfluous... A padlock kind of makes sense as it indicates you might have to request access to be able to talk... but the diamond *shrugs*

Comment: @JonClements it doesn't matter for the question at hand, It would have been changed to *What is the meaining of R* ....